# Module apt_repository: Why is validate_certs not working?

Tags: ansible, apt

I have an Ansible playbook that adds an Apt repository.
The Repo is located on my own server - accessed by HTTPS (with a self-signed cert).

If I put the repo manually in the hosts `sources.list` I get this error when updating the cache.

Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.

Ok, its self-signed. Disable the check and all is fine.

```
apt -o "Acquire::https::Verify-Peer=false" update
```

Very good - now I try to handle it with Ansible.

```yaml
- name: add my repo and update cache
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://myserver/debian bullseye main
    filename: myrepo
    validate_certs: false
    state: present
```

No matter if I set **validate_certs: false** - it fails any time.

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: unknown reason"}
```

If I make the repo public via HTTP and change the URL then all is fine.
Also if I keep it with HTTPS-selfsigned and set

```
Acquire::https::Verify-Peer "false";
```

at the update-seeking hosts apt-config it will work too.

But I expect **validate_certs** to handle that.
So why is it not working??

```
debian 11.6
ansible 2.10.8
python 3.9.2
```

Comment: Just for testing purposes. Does it work when you see `update_cache` to false? And tried running it verbose?

Comment: Does apt logs show you anything more?

Comment: Funny enough, I don't see any use of `validate_certs` in the [module source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt_repository.py) besides the documentation and the declaration of module accepted options. So unless I missed something, this param seems to be totally ignored for time being.

Comment: As requested:
- Apt-logs do not show anything.

- With update_cache: false there is no error.

- No additional information if I run the playbook with --verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `validate_certs` argument to `apt_repository` does not affect the configuration of apt or the repository, it controls whether certs are validated during the module's internal fetching of PPA info.

If you want apt to ignore validation failures, you need to configure apt accordingly.

Comment: So it seems - documentation ca be a bit better at this point.